# Pip: Different Versions From requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

I'm using pip and a requirements file to install my dependencies.

I have the package django-graph-auth in my requirements file.

If I install the package with ***pip install django-graph-auth*** I get version 0.3.1, but if I install it from the requirements file (without specifying a version) I get 0.2.0. Specifying django-graph-auth==0.3.1 in the file doesnt work either (while installing by "hand" works).

Any explanations for this behavior?

Update:
If I put the package in its own requirements file it seems to work, any ideas on how to track down which package it depends on?

Comment: What are the other requirements in the file? One of them might require version 0.2.0.

Comment: Is the pip module that Django uses the same one that your command `'pip'` is linked to? Maybe the version of pip that Django uses needs to be updated or else locate the module on the server and manually try to install `django-graph-auth==0.3.1` and see what error it throws

Comment: Im not using django to install the reqs, Im running pip install -r requirements.txt
@kichik: Will investigate.

Comment: Interesting, if I put it in its own file, it installs properly. Any ideas how to track down the causing package?